# Webview doesn't respect width limit

Tags: ios, webview, width

I'm loading data from a webservice into a webview. The problem is sometimes the data comes with a big image or an iframe that extends the width of the webview. This causes the webview to unformat.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
self.webView.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
self.webView.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
self.webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = YES;
```

Comment: webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight; gives an error and the rest of the code doesn't change anything.

Comment: Available in iOS 7.0 and later. Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW48

Comment: I've checked that but didn't help